# Adding a specific semantic HTML structure in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can anyone help me adding a specific html structure inside this javascript?

```
// If question has >1 true answers and is not a select any, use checkboxes; otherwise, radios
            var input = '<input id="' + optionId + '" name="' + inputName + '" type="' + inputType + '" /> '

            var optionLabel = '<label for="' + optionId + '">' + answer.option + '</label>'

            var answerContent = $('<li></li>')
              .append(input)
              .append(optionLabel)
            answerHTML.append(answerContent)
```

I want to add this HTML structure:

For Radio buttons:

```
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-1">
  <input type="radio" id="option-1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1" checked>
  <span class="mdl-radio__label">First</span>
</label>
```

And for checkboxes:

```
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>
```

And here is the part that decide if the input will be a checkbox or a radio button:

```
// prepare a name for the answer inputs based on the question
        var selectAny = question.select_any ? question.select_any : false,
          forceCheckbox = question.force_checkbox ? question.force_checkbox : false,
          checkbox = (truths > 1 && !selectAny) || forceCheckbox,
          inputName = $element.attr('id') + '_question' + (count - 1),
          inputType = checkbox ? 'checkbox' : 'radio'
```

PS: This is my first experience with javascript, i'm a complete newbie on javascript, so.. if anything is missing, tell me

Comment: That all looks pretty good, no massively obvious problems. Are you having any errors/problems you can describe? (And what is `answerHTML`?)

Comment: I'm using JQuery because the plugin that i'm using for the quiz needs it.. I don't have the knowledge to do make something like this from scratch, i know html and css, but not js..

Comment: answerHTML is the ul that display the aswers radio buttons or checkboxes
`// Now let's append the answers with checkboxes or radios depending on truth count
            var answerHTML = $('<ul class="' + answersClass + '"></ul>')`

Comment: I'm having trouble to adding this custom classes and styles required by the framework (MDL), with the defaut code it just displays vanilla rdb/chk.. i need to render those snippets in the page, not vanilla ones

Comment: oh, btw.. i'm using this for the quiz part [link](https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz/tree/master)